# C# regex parse span

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a requirement where I need to get the link only from this HTML

```
"<span class=""name""><a href=Details.aspx?entityID=1&hash=20&searchFunctionID=53b&type=Advanced&nameSet=Entities&q=a&textSearchType=ExactPhrase&orgTypes=01%2c02%2c03%2c04%2c05%2c06%2c07%2c08%2c09%2c10%2c11%2c12%2c13%2c14%2c15%2c16%2c90%2c96%2c98%2c99> GOOGLE CORPORATION  </a> </span>  <br /> <span class=typeDescription>  09  -  Analytics Company </span>"
```

The output I need is

```
Details.aspx?entityID=1&hash=20&searchFunctionID=53b&type=Advanced&nameSet=Entities&q=a&textSearchType=ExactPhrase&orgTypes=01%2c02%2c03%2c04%2c05%2c06%2c07%2c08%2c09%2c10%2c11%2c12%2c13%2c14%2c15%2c16%2c90%2c96%2c98%2c99
```

I used

```
string sPattern ="[<a href=](.*?(99))";
MatchCollection mcMatches = Regex.Matches(input,sPattern);
foreach (Match m in mcMatches)
{
   Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

This is not giving me right output. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Parsing HTML with Regex? [Bad idea!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) Instead, why not use proper HTML parser, like [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Please don't parse HTML with RegEx.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested above, parsing HTML with Regex is [not very good idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). I recommend you to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) (you can get it from NuGet):

```
HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlDocument();            
hdoc.LoadHtml(@"<span class=""name""><a href=Details.aspx?entityID=1&hash=20&searchFunctionID=53b&type=Advanced&nameSet=Entities&q=a&textSearchType=ExactPhrase&orgTypes=01%2c02%2c03%2c04%2c05%2c06%2c07%2c08%2c09%2c10%2c11%2c12%2c13%2c14%2c15%2c16%2c90%2c96%2c98%2c99> GOOGLE CORPORATION  </a> </span>  <br /> <span class=typeDescription>  09  -  Analytics Company </span>");
var href = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a").Attributes["href"].Value;
```

It gives you value of `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As Shaamaan said, Regex is not the right way to parse HTML, for your example given, a better Regex would be, although no guarantee it will always work:

```
(?:<a href=)([^">]*)
```